# Logarithm function does not have discontinuity

Tags: limits, continuity, curves

I cannot understand why the function $\displaystyle{\frac{\ln x}{x-1}}$ does not have a discontinuity at $x=1$?

Comment: Of course it has a discontinuity at $x=1$ There is a hole in the graph. That is certainly a discontinuity, but a removable one by defining a piece wise function, using the result in the answer provided below

Comment: It is, OFC. The graphs on WA normally don't show that.

Comment: Alright alright alright :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At $x=1$ you have $\frac{0}{0}$, which is indeterminate. If you work out the limit of that function as $x$ approaches $1$, then you get (using [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\ln x}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1}=1.$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice, let $x-1=t\implies t\to 0\ as\ x\to 1$ hence, $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+t)}{t}$$ Using Taylor's series expansion $\ln(t+1)$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t-\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t^3}{3}+O(t^3)}{t}$$ $$=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(1-\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{3}+O(t^2)\right)$$ $$=\left(1-0\right)=\color{red}{1}$$

Comment: I am very thankful for posting this even though I have already selected an answer. I love bent aware of different ways of tackling the same problem. However, I lost you as soon as you mentioned Taylor's series expansion. Though, I know it is in my further maths curriculum, which I am to start studying in about two weeks. So I will definitely come back to this :)